# How to send a random text from a list through sendkeys() using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, random

I want selenium to randomly pick a text and then type it out.

Code:

```
driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.editor-styles-wrapper .editor-post-title__input').send_keys("Granny Script")`
```

That is the element.

I would list the 5 texts for example "Hello, halal, no halal, hey, milk" and would like to randomly pick and type one of the sentences/words.

Comment: Can you share the url of the website please

Answer (score 0):

[`random.choice(list)`](https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/) chooses a random item from a sequence. The seq can be a `list`, `tuple`, `string` or any iterable like range.

An example to send a random string from a list is as follows:

- Code block:

  ```
  import random

  random_texts = ['Hello', 'halal', 'no halal', 'hey', 'milk']
  for i in range(3):
      print(random.choice(random_texts))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  halal
  milk
  no halal
  ```

---

### This usecase

```
random_texts = ['Hello', 'halal', 'no halal', 'hey', 'milk']
driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.editor-styles-wrapper.editor-post-title__input').send_keys(random.choice(random_texts))
```

PS: In *CSS_SELECTOR* the *classnames* should be appended through a dot (`.`) character and **no** additional spaces.